# Pass json file to client using Express routes

Tags: javascript, json, express, handlebars.js

I'm trying to send a json file to the client, but I fail to do so. I get internal errors (500). Can someone help me out? Also, I use Handlebars as view engine.

app.js:

```
[...]
var APIconditions = {};
var APIhourly = {};

function getWeatherData() {
    var data = ['/conditionsWU.json', '/hourlyWU.json'];
    request(data[0], function(err, res, body) {
        if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
            APIconditions = JSON.parse(body);
        }
    });
    request(data[1], function(err, res, body) {
        if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
            APIhourly = JSON.parse(body);
        }
    });
}
[...]
```

index.js:

```
[...]
router.get('/conditions' , function(req, res, next) {
    res.json(APIconditions);
});

router.get('/hourly' , function(req, res, next) {
    res.json(APIhourly);
});
[...]
```

client.js:

```
[...]
function getWeather() {
    var APIconditions = 'conditions';
    var APIhourly = 'hourly';

$.getJSON(APIconditions, function (data) {
    [...]
});
$.getJSON(APIhourly, function (data) {
        [...]
    });
[...]
```

Comment: Do you get error in the nodeJS console? seems like you have unhandeled exceptions

Comment: Also, did you export and require objects from `app.js`? I wonder if your error is that `APIconditions` and `APIhourly` are undefined in index.js

Comment: @OmriLuzon Yes I might have unhandled exceptions. For now, I'm just using the skeleton that Express Generator provides. What do you mean with "export and require objects"? How do I do that exactly? `global.APIconditions` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @OmriLuzon It's already fixed man. See answer below. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access `APIconditions` or `APIhourly` from another file without specifying it.

The simplest solution would be to attach them to the global scope, so you have access to them from everywhere.

```
global.APIconditions = {}
global.APIhourly = {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this. I'm not getting any errors anymore. However, the objects are empty in the client. What am I missing? :(

Comment: @Zarif hard to tell. Make sure `getWeatherData()` is called and try to find where the data "disappears". ( are they empty in the index.js file?). Instead of just write the `!err` log the error to the console. To help I need as much information as possible.

Comment: I logged the error to the console. Apparently, `/conditionsWU.json` isn't a correct URI. I fixed it by using `fs.readFile()` instead of `request()`. Thanks for your help!